# React Native TouchableHighlight not working with Sectionlist

Tags: react-native

I've got a `SectionList`, and for every row in the list I want to be able to detect a click event.

```
renderList() {
if (this.state.searching) {
  return (
    <SectionList
      sections={this.state.data}
      renderSectionHeader={this.props.renderSectionHeader}
      renderItem={this.props.renderItem}
    />
  );
}

return null;
}

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>

    <Animated.View
      style={{ opacity: 1 - this.state.backgroundColor }}
      pointerEvents={this.state.searching ? 'none' : undefined}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </Animated.View>

    <Animated.View
      style={[
        styles.backgroundColorView,
        { opacity: this.state.backgroundColor },
      ]}
    />

    <Animated.View
      style={[styles.searchResults, { top: this.state.yPos }]}
    >
      <TextInput
        ref={(input) => { this.searchBar = input; }}
        style={styles.textInput}
        value={this.props.query}
        onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
        maxLength={100}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        onFocus={this.onFocus}
        onBlur={this.onUnSearch}
      />

      {this.renderList()}

    </Animated.View>
  </View>
);
```

For my renderItem method, I'm passing in the following `PureComponent`, which is just a `Text` contained in a `TouchableHighlight`.

```
class SubjectSearchItem extends React.PureComponent {
render() {
const item = this.props.item;
return (
  <TouchableHighlight
    onPress={() => console.log(item)}
  >
    <View style={{
      marginHorizontal: 20,
      marginVertical: 10,
    }}
    >
      <Text>{`${item.item.long_name} (${item.item.short_name})`}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
);
}
}
```

and here's the `renderItem` prop I'm passing in

```
const renderItem = item => (
      <SubjectSearchItem
        item={item}
      />
    );
```

The problem is, no click events are being detected. The row isn't getting highlighted, and the `onPress` isn't being fired. Any ideas?

Note: seems like this has been an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14155) for a little while

Comment: Are `SubjectItem` and `SubjectSearchItem` the same?

Comment: @Harlan Yes it's a default export. Let me edit that though.